# How to set the target schema using osm2pgrouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

Is it possible to set the target database schema using osm2pgrouting?

After some debate and troubleshooting, I've decided to host my OSM-based pgRouting data in the same database as the rest of my data, but want to use a different schema (one big issue was using dblink, which I can't get to work anyway).

However, osm2pgrouting doesn't expose the ability to specify the target schema.

Comment: I added the feature request to osm2pgrouting

Comment: @Vicky that's great! I much appreciate that!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I've been able to do it (I think it works for osm2pgrouting, but haven't tried recently)

Is to first change the search_path of your database temporarily so preferred schema is first:

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdb SET search_path = osm_data, public;
```

Then run osm2pgrouting

Alternatively you could create a user specifically for loading and then set the search_path for that user (or name the same as the schema) assuming you didn't mess with your db search_path.

```
ALTER ROLE osm_user IN DATABASE yourdb
     SET search_path = osm_data,public;
```

then always load with that user.

It's not ideal I know.  Probably worthwhile putting in a feature request here:  https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting

Comment: that's great - worked like a charm. Barring the feature request now in osm2pgrouting, this is a great workaround...thanks again!

Comment: BTW I recently added the schema feature in  osm2pgrouitng.  So should show in next release.  https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/tree/with-schema